# How to make opencv for real time system?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, computer-vision

Real time system requires a fast & efficient platform. I wonder which combination is suitable for real time image processing: OpenCV-Python, OpenCV-MVStudio (C++), OpenCV-Matlab or OpenCV-Java? I had read about CUDA, but if I don't want to use CUDA for my project, is there any way to develop a fast system?

Comment: This is a way too broad question, because of multiple issues. Firstly that "real time" can mean a lot of things, and secondly that achieving it will depend wholly on your application and available resources. I would create a new question detailing exactly what you want to be done, and what constraints you have (computing resources, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can comment on MATLAB, Python and C++, but not Java:

To run OpenCV in MATLAB you will need something along the lines of mexopencv (http://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/). This compiles many of the OpenCV functions (not all functions are included) into mex files which MATLAB can read and use. It works but is probably not the fastest solution for real time applications. But it is useful for prototyping.

Running OpenCV in Python is easier and runs more efficiently, though it is still "indirect" as it requires a Python wrapper (as OpenCV is written in optimized C/C++).

The most efficient solution for real-time algorithms would be to use the native language of OpenCV, i.e. C++, avoiding the translation step between languages.

CUDA, or parallel processing in general, is an option for all these platforms. However whether it will benefit the speed of your code depends largely on the project itself. Often parallelising something can make it run slower instead of faster. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_slowdown for info.

Hope this helps!